# Cannot connect to fresh installed SQL Server database in azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, cloud, connection-string

I got an error when try to connect SQL Server database that I was installed at azure cloud. Below is the error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060)
```

I already add firewall setting for all IP, `0.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`.I expected that the server can be accessed. Still, I am getting the same error

Comment: Once check the network some time the server will not connect for Lans.

Comment: Have you double- and triple-checked that you're using the correct domain name in your connection string? Can you resolve the domain name to an IP address with `ping` or `tracert`? Can `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName yourAzureSqlServerDomainName -Port 1433` connect successfully from a PowerShell prompt?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to connect to My SQL server I got the same error:

[image]

In my case I am having issue with my network, I am using my corporate network. I switched to another network, and I tried to connect again then the connection was successful.

Along with that check below option while connecting to the SQL server:

- Make sure outbound traffic over port 1433 will allowed by your network's firewall.
- Once check you have given correct details of SQL server.

For more information you can refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-connection).